# Optimizing pd.read_sql

Tags: python, sql, performance, pyodbc

```
conn1 = pyodbc.connect('DSN=LUDP-Training Presto',uid='*****', pwd='****', autocommit=True) 

 sql_query =        "SELECT             zsourc_sy, zmsgeo, salesorg, crm_begdat, zmcn, zrtm, crm_obj_id, zcrmprod, prod_hier, hier_type, zsoldto, zendcst, crmtgqtycv, currency, zwukrs, netvalord, zgtnper,zsub_4_t \
                    FROM                `prd_updated`.`bw_ms_zocsfs05l_udl` \
                    WHERE               zdcgflag = 'DCG' AND crm_begdat >= '20200101' AND zmsgeo IN ('AP', 'LA', 'EMEA', 'NA')"
```

I have to load the following query into a pandas dataframe but the pd.read_sql statement has been loading for more than a couple hours since the table is > 10 million rows of data. Is there a way to speed this process up?

```
contract_table = pd.read_sql(sql_query,conn1)
```

Comment: Please dont use images in the question. Edit your question and share the query in text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `chunksize` param to the `read_sql` function ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)), which turns it into a generator that returns an iterator of dataframes with the specified number of rows.

```py
df_iter = pd.read_sql(sql_query,conn1, chunksize=100)

for df in df_iter:
    for row in df: # 100 rows in each dataframe in this example
        # do work here
```

Generators are an efficient way of processing data that's too large to all fit in memory at once.